# Does the Powerful Build trait stack with the benefit to carrying capacity from the Totem Warrior Barbarian's Aspect of the Beast (Bear) feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, barbarian, stacking, encumbrance

Does the Goliath's carrying capacity increase from its **Powerful Build** feature stack with the Barbarian's carrying capacity doubling from its **Bear Totem** feature? For example, would those two together give a character with Strength 20 a carrying capacity of 1200 lbs?

Comment: You should change the title of the question. Lifting is different from carrying capacity. One is active and requires a roll, the other does not. This question is about the latter. This may be a bit nitpicky.

Comment: @Jason_c_o: Neither requires a roll by RAW (assuming your character's not trying to lift/carry something beyond their limit, at least). They're both based on your Strength score (push/drag/lift limit is twice your carrying capacity, which is equal to Str score times 15).

Comment: True. But I still feel there's a difference between lifting and carrying capacity. If it's within your capacity, then you're carrying it. I just read "lifting" as implying the character is attempting to lift it.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, these abilities should stack fully. While previous editions had rules around stacking multipliers, 5e doesn't, and even if it did, Powerful Build doesn't directly multiply your carrying capacity - it just makes you count as Large.

Your carrying capacity as a Str 20 character = 20 × 15 = 300.

Then being a Large creature (from Powerful Build) doubles your carrying capacity to 600.

Finally, the Bear Totem feature doubles your carrying capacity to 1200.

This isn't particularly imbalanced - you had to work reasonably hard to get it, and carrying capacity doesn't matter that much anyway. Besides, it's not enough to let you beat the Elephant :(