# Can a Path of the Totem Warrior barbarian have different totems chosen for each subclass feature at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian

I was creating a goliath [Path of the Totem Warrior barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior) (PHB, p. 50), and had chosen the Bear totem for his 3rd-level [Totem Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#TotemSpirit-100) feature. The 6th-level [Aspect of the Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#AspectoftheBeast-101) feature, however, felt like overkill for a Bear totem/goliath combination, since the combination would double his carrying capacity twice. I wondered if I could choose a different totem at 6th level.

I did notice the following language for each subsequent totem choice after the first (at levels 6 and 14):

> At ___ level, you gain a magical benefit based on the totem animal of
> your choice. You can choose the same animal you selected at 3rd level
> or a different one.

My first assumption was that this is like swapping out spells known when you level in some spell casting classes, such as the bard (i.e. if you choose Wolf at 6th level, your abilities switch over to a Wolf Totem barbarian). After all, in online discussions, people often refer to a Bear Totem barbarian, or a Wolf Totem barbarian, but never do I see reference to a multi-totemed Barbarian. However, I wanted the 6th-level Wolf ability, but didn't want to give up the 3rd level Bear ability.

**Can a Path of the Totem Warrior barbarian have multiple totems?** That is, can they have different totems chosen for each subclass feature at the same time?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [Can a Totem Warrior Barbarian choose a second Totem Spirit in place of an Aspect of the Beast?](/questions/172437)

Comment: Related: [Does the Powerful Build trait stack with the benefit to carrying capacity from the Totem Warrior Barbarian's Aspect of the Beast (Bear) feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62034/does-the-powerful-build-trait-stack-with-the-benefit-to-carrying-capacity-from-t)

Comment: Thanks for the related question. I have edited mine so as not to mislead.

Answer (score 23):

### Yes, you can have different totem animals for different level abilities.

Though few people discuss multi-totemed Barbarians, this is the RAW of the class's wording. Consider the 10th level ability, Spirit Walker:

> At 10th level, you can cast the commune with nature spell, but only as
>   a ritual. When you do so, a spiritual version of **one of the animals
>   you chose for Totem Spirit or Aspect of the Beast** appears to you to
>   convey the information you seek.

*(emphasis mine)*

This quite unambiguously conveys the idea that you can make different totem choices at different levels, and that they do not have to agree.